# BigQuery Google Analytics: count number of sessions and goal completion if custom dimension of the first hit of a session has a certain value

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery

I am using Bigquery to pull Google Analytics Sessions and goal completions if the first hit's custom dimension equals certain values. The session count was right but goal completion count was way less than expected.

In GA, my segment used for QA is 
*include sessions sequence start first user interaction

custom dimension 10 is one of 1,5*

Goal definition is
Event Action = 'event action value 1' or 'event action value 2'

Here is my code

```
SELECT 
  ---   goal completion
  COUNT(DISTINCT(
    IF
      (REGEXP_contains(hits.eventinfo.eventaction   , '(event action value 1|event action value 2)'),
        CONCAT(fullVisitorId, CAST(visitStartTime AS STRING)),
        NULL))) AS Goals, 
---Sessions
  COUNT(DISTINCT CONCAT(fullVisitorId, CAST(visitStartTime AS STRING))) AS Sessions,
FROM
    `123456789.ga_sessions_20200201` as Data,
    unnest(hits) as hits
WHERE totals.visits = 1
    and EXISTS (select 1 from unnest(hits.customDimensions) where index = 10 and value in ('1', '5') and hits.time = 0)
```

Comment: Hello, in order to better support you in this, you could share an example of the input data and the expected outcome of that Data and what you are getting from your query that is not expected. This way I can try to help you.

Comment: Hi Gonzalo, I am not allowed to share any company's data. But the data is similar to the
Google Analytics sample dataset for BigQuery. All I want to know is whether my code replicate the Google Analytics segment correctly. Thanks

Comment: Hello, I've checked your code and it seems good to me. Both the Goal and Sessions definitions seem properly set up and the filtering (where/exists) also looks fine. Make sure that all the filters have the proper value and do not restrict more than expected the data. I've tested it for some tables I have and the results are the expected ones but my tables may lack similarity to your use case.
You should try to create a "dummy" table that mimics your use case (with made up data) to show what you want to obtain versus what you actually obtain. In that way we will be able to help you further.